# Create an arrow div in css or svg webkit only

Tags: html, css, svg, webkit

I have to create an interface (slideshow management) where slides are previewed inside squares with a slight arrow feeling.
How can I achieve this? I feel like I'm over css's limits
I really don't care about browser compatibility, it is a webkit only platform

Once I manage to get the shape, I think the rest will be easy css (border, shadow, overlapping, ...)

this is a preview:

[image]

Any idea how to achieve this? Boxes won't always be the same size/ratio.. they can be portrait and landscape.. whatever actually.
Is it possible using some vector based mask layer or so?

Comment: Please provide some starting code for us to look at, in order to better advise you. Remember that StackOverflow is driven by volunteers who take time out of their schedules to help, and the implicit requirement is that those who ask questions provide examples of what they have tried and what has failed before those volunteers respond with answers. There are several ways to approach your problem, but which ways will be most apt to your situation depend largely on what tech you know, what your skills are, and what your environmental constraints are (WebKit in this case, right?).

Comment: This can be your way   http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/masking/adobe/#toc-clip-path-property

Comment: Keep in mind, it's not supported by any version of IE and Firefox.

Comment: @mori57 I know.. I didn't asked someone to give me a fully functional code, or to work freely for me as some do.. I just asked if someone was aware of a technique existing. I don't think there are several ways because of the final result. Just asked for an idea, a path. vals understood this this ways and gave me the perfect answer. If vals could put it as an answer, I can accept it.
Anyway, I don't think posting a question asking for a path to go, with an example image to be clear really deserves a downvote.

Comment: @vals Please put your comment as an answer so I can accept it, this is the way to go if anyone want's to achieve the same.

Comment: "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. `Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.` See also: Stack Overflow question checklist." - http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic (emphasis added) ... not trying to be a jerk, here, but it looks like you have some code experience, and you could have at least included some snippet of what you were starting with so that others could respond appropriately. In any event, glad someone found something that worked for you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed into rendering it nearly the way I wanted, thanks Vals for pointing me into the good direction.

A Fiddle with the result (only works in chrome and mobile safari) : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k75AE/2/)

I had to use a container div to apply the shadow, as the clipping is processed after shadow render.. But the container Div is rectangular, so a simple shadow doesn't work. css filters work in this case.
Same for the white border, using a shadow filter on another div works.

```
.arrowClip 
{
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0 , 100% 80%, 50% 100%, 0 80% );
}

.arrowContainer 
{ 
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.9)) ;  
}
.arrowStroke 
{  
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 2px rgba(255,255,255,1)) ; 
}
```